Use user-entered values into the Azure pipeline and use in PowerShell
I am creating an Azure pipeline in which I want to invoke a PowerShell script. In the YAML pipeline, I want to pass variables while running the pipeline, which should be used in the PowerShell script. I have tried the below:
parameters:

    name: User
    displayName: Enter user name
     type: string
    default: ''

stages:

 - stage: usercreation
   displayName: User Creation
  jobs:
- job: usercreation
  displayName: 'User Creation'
  steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: 'User creation'
      inputs:
        ScriptPath: './templates/pwscript/dbusers.ps1'

I cant figure out how to pass on the user parameter in the dbusers.ps1 script where i want to use the variable User in the powershell script. Here I want the user to give users in comma separated values and then use it as array in ps script

Have you tried as the suggestions shared in below answers? Is any of the answers working for you? @Aviator

You should use scriptArguments
parameters:
    name: User
    displayName: Enter user name
    type: string
    default: ''

stages:

 - stage: usercreation
   displayName: User Creation
  jobs:
- job: usercreation
  displayName: 'User Creation'
  steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: 'User creation'
      inputs:
        scriptPath: './templates/pwscript/dbusers.ps1'
        scriptArguments: -Arg1 ${{ parameters.User }}


how can this get handled if user passes comma separated values? @krzystof

@Aviator this I tested this and it will work with simple values such as dbuser1,dbuser2,dbuser3 if your script param is of type [string[]]

Krzysztof you have an extra $ at the end of -Arg1 ${{ parameters.User }}$

@Aviator you should do error handling in your script. You are not able to force user to provide expected format.

If you want to pass one or more than one user names into the PowerShell script, as @Rui Jarimba mentioned, you can define a parameter as string type array (string[]) in the script to receive the list of user names.
See below example as reference.

The PowerShell script.
# templates/pwscript/dbusers.ps1

param (
    [string[]] $users
)

Write-Host $users
Write-Host "--------------------"

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Write-Host "$user"
    Write-Host "--------------------"
}


the pipeline YAML.
parameters:
- name: Users
  displayName: 'Enter user names:'
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ArmConnection'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: 'templates/pwscript/dbusers.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-users ${{ parameters.Users }}'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    pwsh: true


The result.




NOTE:
If a user name contains whitespace, you must use the double/single quotes to surround the user name when entering the parameter value. Otherwise, the value will be truncated by the whitespace when passing as argument to the PowerShell script.



